# RoutingError in Rails application on dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost, actioncontroller

I want to test sample rails application on shared Dreamhost account, so i have created sample application with ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.2.8 and mysql database. on localhost it works fine, but after uploading it on Dreamhost its giving error when i clicks on "About your application’s environment" like given below.

here is the detail error from production.log file

> Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 180.87.200.112 at Sat Oct 06
>   01:38:01 -0700 2012
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/rails/info/properties"):
>
> Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 180.87.200.112 at Sat Oct 06
>   01:37:50 -0700 2012
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/rails.png"):

Comment: change and try - "/assets/rails.png" to "assets/rails.png"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure following in your production file.

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: worked for png file now rails application showing image but first problem still remains   Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 180.87.200.112 at Sat Oct 06 01:38:01 -0700 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rails/info/properties"):

Comment: try to run production in local

Comment: production in local means how? please give me some details as i am a beginner.

Comment: you have two files in config/environments folder like production.rb and development.rb. right?

Comment: in local the development.rb file will run. if you upload files means the production.rd file will run.